# What to do when an Ambulance can't pass you?

Tags: germany, driving, emergencies

So here's the deal: Earlier I was driving on the highway to work, which currently is under construction work. Because of that, one of the two lanes is closed and the second one is slightly narrowed. There is no emergency lane either. Then their was this ambulance driving right behind me, with sirens on and blue light flashing, so it surely was an emergency. In situations like that, as a driver, you obviously drive to the side and let the ambulance pass. However, because of the construction work this simply was not possible.

**What is the right thing to do in such a situation?** Is there anything written down in law (maybe the Straßenverkehrsordnung).

I tried to speed up a little  to at least make it through constructions quicker. But the drivers in front of me didn't, so that was pretty much useless.

Answer (score 2):

§38 StVO Wegerecht

You are required to make way when practible

- i. e. within the rules of the StVO
- it is assumed that a driver does not have the needed overview to correctly access the situation

If nothing else is possible, infringements are tolerated.

A driver should note date, time and (where practical) ambulance number, so that if a fine is sent (red light, stop line etc.) it can be cancelled due to an emergency which takes higher priority.

From your description you did everything possible [you can't force the other to go faster].

Flashing light once to catch the attention of the driver in front may have been possible, but they may have had someone in front of them as well.